# Accessing map from MapLayer component (works on previous react-leaflet version)

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I am trying to display route between two points on leaflet map. For that purpose I am using leaflet-routing-machine. But I have problem with passing map object to leaflet route component.

map_container.js

```
...
        return (
            <Map ref='map' center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Routing map={this.refs.map} from={[51.599684, 15.27539]} to={[51.602292, 15.295128]} />
            </Map>
        )
...
```

routing.js

```
import {MapLayer} from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-routing-machine';

export default class RoutingMachine extends MapLayer {
    componentWillMount() {
        super.componentWillMount();
        this.leafletElement.addTo(this.props.map);
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }

    createLeafletElement (props) {
        const {from, to} = this.props;
        console.log(this.props)
        var leafletElement = L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(from[0], from[1]),
                L.latLng(to[0], to[1]),
            ],
        });
        return leafletElement;
    }
}
```

Errors I get:

```
{map: undefined, from: Array(2), to: Array(2)}

bundle.js:69506 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSize' of undefined
    at NewClass.onAdd (bundle.js:69506)
    at NewClass.onAdd (bundle.js:68679)
    at NewClass.addTo (bundle.js:26718)
```

But what is most interesting - **everything does work perfectly on "react-leaflet": "1.1.0" version, but on 1.1.1 and above it breaks.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, after a while I've found a solution. *Cannot read property 'getSize' of undefined* error was caused by map passed to refs only after whole module has loaded. It can be fixed by adding:

```
return ( this.map ? 
        <Map onClick={(e) => this._mapClickEvent(e)} className="main-screen-map-container" center={position} 
             zoom={this.state.zoom} ref={map => this.map = map}> 

          <TileLayer 
              attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors" 
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" 
          /> 
          <Routing map={this._getMap()} from={[11.11, 12.12]} to={[11.11, 12.12]}
                   by={this.props.busstops}/>  
        </Map> 
        : 
        <Map onClick={(e) => this._mapClickEvent(e)} className="main-screen-map-container" center={position} 
             zoom={this.state.zoom} ref={map => this.map = map}> 

          <TileLayer 
              attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors" 
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" 
          /> 
        </Map>
```

Which checks if map is already defined, then rerenders it with road on it. Depending on the rest of your code (if you are fetching some data using Redux and setting state which forces update) it may be required to also add following code:

```
 componentDidMount() { 
    console.log("map did mount " + this.map); 
    this.forceUpdate() 
  }
```

That should fix it. PS ternary operator could also be refactored by removing redundant code and just adding

```
 _addRouting() {
    if (this.map) {
      return (
          <div>
            <Routing map={this._getMap()} from={[11.11, 12.12]} to={[11.11, 12.12]}
                     by={this.props.busstops}/>
          </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

and then injecting it in render method.

Still have no idea why this problem didn't occur on older versions of react-leaflet.